# Identifying this control for Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

This is the first Xamarin.Forms app I try to create, so please bear with me.

I'm learning about `Xamarin.Forms`, and I'm creating my first app (with a map) that will run in the android emulator. I've already added the map, so life is good.

I also understand that, unlike asp.net webforms or Windows forms, I cannot drag & drop controls to the form. I also don't know what the available controls for each platform look like.

With that said, I would like to add the following control to my app. I have no idea how it's called, but it's *sort of* a panel on the bottom half of the screen. This panel will include a list (much like a gridview).

[image]

I saw this [Xamarin page with a list of standard controls](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/mobile/StandardControls/), but I don't know how to identify them. Even worse, I don't know what to search for in the web.

I would like to know where I can find information on adding that control to a form and populating it with data (like an asp.net gridview)

Comment: Your link to the list of controls are for native Xamarin apps, not to be confused with Xamarin.Forms apps. Here is a reference to Xamarin.Forms controls: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/controls/

Answer (score 0):

Something like that is usually rendered using an [ActionSheet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/pop-ups#guiding-users-through-tasks)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't such a control. On iOS it is done by partially covering the screen while presenting the TableViewController. You can't do something like that on Xamarin.Forms. You can do that only on native projects.

There might be some plugins that may do some of that work for you but I don't think any of them fits your request, but you can try how far you can get with this one: https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup

Please note that Xamarin.Forms don't cover all native controls and especially not all properties of those controls. And while you may extend their reach in various ways if you are after copying everything you see in some app it is better to think of some other technology.

Also of note, Android doesn't support everything that iOS supports, so if you see something on iOS screen (like above) it may not be supported on Android, no matter what technology you use you will have to build a very custom solution, which probably isn't part of your first app.